# How to re-acquire InterProcessMutex after client restart

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, apache-curator

I'm using [this curator recipe](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/shared-lock.html) to synchronize access to shared state b/w multiple clients. The problem is that if a process dies while holding the lock, the client fails with:

```
IllegalMonitorStateException You do not own the lock: /classifier-job-lock  
org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.locks.InterProcessMutex.release (InterProcessMutex.java:140)
```

What is the best plan-of-action in this scenario?

Comment: "client can not re-acquire it after restarting" - why not? After the original client's session expires, the lock will become available. Can you post an example?

Comment: @Randgalt Edited the question to include the error I'm seeing. Please elaborate on the client session.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `InterProcessMutex`. This behaves like JDK locks in that the same thread that acquires the lock must be the thread that releases the lock. Note: the doc for this class should be improved.

Instead, try using `InterProcessSemaphoreMutex` which doesn't have this restriction.